# Cropping images to the same height and width?

Tags: jquery, image-resizing

I'm talking about something like [500px.com](http://500px.com/popular). Every image is the same height and width and it looks great when its laid out that way. I've been looking for a bit and can't seem to find a tutorial on achieving this. I do know how to simply resize images but I'm looking for something like this specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing the image resizing/cropping client side, try using a server side set of utilities.

Assuming you're running PHP on your server and can install ImageMagik (if it's not already there)

Have a look at [Jue Wangs "Opticrop" library](http://jueseph.com/2010/06/opticrop-usage-and-implementation/)

Comment: That site seems to be down, but still in the archive.org repo. http://web.archive.org/web/20111212093014/http://jueseph.com/2010/06/opticrop-usage-and-implementation/

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If the source images are of uniform height and width already then resizing them whilst maintaining aspect is straightforward, albeit increasing size will eventually lead to distortion.

However if they are of varying height/width you'll distort by just forcing them to a uniform size. You would need to crop probably and loose parts on the edges. Best way to do this is probably find the center of the image and work out a width and height that's in the aspect you want from there.

Once you have that image you can then resize up or down.

It's probably quicker/more efficient to do this in server side code though.

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to find any material on how to accomplish this though. Do you know of any?